# Can I make a windows form application in Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows 8?

Tags: visual-studio

Seems likely that I am not able to create a windows form application using the Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 under Windows 8. The default templaters are only for creating apps rather than traditional normal windowed applications.

Is there any way I could find the template or find a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Please close your question by marking it answered.  Tick the check-mark to the left of the post that helped you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot.

Download Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop instead.

- [Link for online installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832280&clcid=0x415)
- [Link for ISO file](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9832270&clcid=0x415)
- [Visual Studio download page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/plk/downloads)

Answer (score 1):

Actually yes, you can do that manually, by adding the references to the project (`System.Windows.Forms`) and changing the output type in the properties of the project, and adding classes - you have to manually do the whole thing..

Answer (score 0):

To Expand RobDev's answer, you can actually do this. I will show you an example of how to do this in Visual Studio Express 2015 for Web, probably same applies for 2013 version.

Steps.:

- Create an empty solution

[image: Empty solution]

- Create a `.dll` library project

[image: Create .dll project]

- Change output in project properties to Windows Application. To do so, right click on the new added project and pick "Properties". There, you can change "Output Type" dropdown in Application tab.

[image: changing output]

- Add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` to your project (by right-clicking => Add Reference to your Reference option under your project)

[image: reference added]

- Set the project to Startup Project, by right-clicking the project and choosing "Set up as Startup Project"

[image]

- add a main method to the generated class (you can rename it to `Main`). It will need this code to start.

  ```
  using System.Windows.Forms;

  namespace ClassLibrary1
  {
      public class Class1
      {
          public static void Main()
          {
              Application.Run(new Form());
          }
      }
  }
  ```

and voila! That will create a new fresh Form. You could use a starting point whatever form you want. To do so, add a new `.cs` class and make it inherit from `Form` class.

The toolbox to customize forms is available at View => Toolbox menu.